# Openfiler data recovery after OS drive failed

Tags: network-attached-storage, openfiler

About to set up a NAS/SAN using Openfiler with the Openfiler OS on drive1, drive2 and drive3 will be used to store data (RAID 1 setup).

In case of drive1 failed, would my data stored in the RAID 1 array (drive2 + drive2) be recoverable after I replace drive1 with a good disk with a fresh install of Openfiler again?

I tried this on a VM setup but the new Openfiler install can only detect that exist a RAID volume, the web GUI has no entry point to link back the data volume.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenFiler uses pretty standard Linux methods for setting up its storage. The Drive2/Drive3 setup will be based in LVM. Once you get a Linux operating system back on to Drive1 after a failure, it should pick up the fact that the other disks have recognizable storage on them. Whether or not the GUI will pick this up remains to be seen, but the data will all be there.